# combine multiple tables into separate rows and columns

Tags: sqlite, union-all

I have an issue with combining tables in SQLite. Say I have 3 tables in an SQLite database. Each table has 10 columns.

There is only one common column to all 3 tables which is "time", which is given as a string of numbers. I want to amalgamate all three tables, and keep the common time column, so I'd end up with a single "time" column plus 27 other columns which are all distinct. I then want to order by amalgamated table by the time column.

The issue is that the time values in each table are completely random and distinct, so I am not able to join based on a common time value. So the number of rows in the amalgamated table would be equal to no.rows in table 1 + no.rows in table 2 + no.rows in table 3. I've thought about INNER JOINS etc but this doesn't fit due to there being no common values...

Many thanks for any suggestions!

**Edited**

Table 1
Time,     Column 1
100012,  Blue
100015,  Red
100018,  Yellow

Table 2
Time, Column 2
12414,  Sofa
12416,  Chair

Table 3
Time, Column 3
159801, Bird
157981, Squirrel
179719, Bear

Desired output:
Time, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3
12414,  NULL, Sofa, NULL
12416,  NULL, Chair, NULL
100012,  Blue, NULL, NULL
100015,  Red, NULL, NULL
100018,  Yellow, NULL, NULL
157981, NULL, NULL, Squirrel
179719, NULL, NULL, Bear

Query:
SELECT * FROM Table1
(Some sort of join)
* FROM Table 2
(Some sort of join)
*FROM Table 3
ORDER BY Time;

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with

Comment: I've added some example data - I don't believe it really adds any value though.

Comment: @CJW what you posted isn't example data. Post your table schema (ie the CREATE TABLE statements), example data (ie the INSERT INTO statements) and actual expected results. Not "something like".

Comment: The data I'm using is company data, and I do not wish to disclose it.

Comment: @CJW don't post all 27 columns either. You should be able to explain what you want with eg 2 columns and `time` per table. Make sure you explain what `time` values you want to get in the results and how you expect to combine rows that differ by milliseconds

Comment: @CJW you don't need to. You can *easily* create test data to demonstrate what you want. Right now it's impossible to guess what you ask. Do you want to aggregate data per second? Use some other combination of time? What? You can't expect an answer when you don't explain what you want

Comment: I've added something a bit more helpful - could you let me know if that explains my question?

Answer (score 0):

A join combines values from multiples tables into the same row. But you want separate rows; this can be done with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT Time, Column1, NULL AS Column2, NULL AS Column3 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Time, NULL,    Column2,         NULL            FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT Time, NULL,    NULL,            Column3         FROM Table3
ORDER BY Time;
```

Comment: Hi CL, thanks for your response with this. This works, however the issue is that the column titles are now 1. Time, 2. Column 1, 3. NULL, 3. NULL
Is there a way to rename the columns such that I can have 1. Time 2. Column 1; 3. Column 2; 4. Column 3?

Comment: The column titles are determined by the AS clauses.

Comment: The problem I've experienced is that when you try to alter a column title (e.g. Price AS Column2, Length AS Column 3) returns an error stating that 'Price' doesn't exist in Table1? I.e. it doesn't seem possible to rename columns to whatever I want.

Comment: Why did you replace `NULL` with `Price`? You want to replace the alias name.